# command line REGEDIT command (edit) without a popup

Tags: windows-7, command-line-interface, batch-file, batch, windows-registry

I am attempting to disable UAC via a batch file with a REGEDIT command, and everything works - but, I need to be able to do this without clicking.  When I run the:

```
REGEDIT /S somefile.reg
```

It works fine, except requires and initial click to allow this command.  Is there any way around this?  I am (temporarily) disabling UAC with the registry edit, but until then it is enabled.  Thank you.

Comment: Well, first you need to disable UAC, and then you can...

Comment: @womble - that is what the registry edit is doing, but until the registry edit runs, UAC is on - I am looking for a way around that.

Comment: Apparently it's too early in the morning for sarcasm.

Comment: It rather involves being on the other side of the airtight hatchway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chicken and egg, eh?

Seriously, though, what you're trying to do isn't "supposed" to be possible because UAC (though disclaimed by Microsoft as not being a formal security boundary) is a security boundary of sorts.

In a domain environment you should be controlling User Account Control from Group Policy (the "User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode" setting under "Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options" in the computer section of Group Policy is what you're probably looking for).

If you're in a non-domain environment then you'll need to run the script in an already-elevated context. As @womble says in his comment you'll need to bypass UAC in order to disable UAC without invoking UAC. A computer startup script would be one place that you could run this. To install it as a startup script, though, you'll have to be elevated. You're back to the chicken and egg, then.

Comment: It looks like UAC is doing exactly what it was designed to... damnit :P

Answer (score 2):

If you are accessing locations in the registry that does not require admin privileges you can use `__COMPAT_LAYER` environment variable.Just execute this before using regedit:

```
set __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker
```